# How to make tags randomly switch places?

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-ui-sortable

I have several `<li>` tags under one id, such as:

```
<div id="myID">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</div>
```

I would like them to randomly switch places on rollover. I thought perhaps with the Sortable jQuery effect? but not sure ... any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

randomly?

```
$('#myID').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $('#myID li').sort(function(){ return Math.random() - .5; }).each(
        function(){
            $('#myID').append(this);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post on the subject:

- [Sorting elements with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery-shuffle, use **mouseenter** though, otherwise your "li" will shuffle furiously.
http://mktgdept.com/js/jquery-shuffle.js?v0.0.1

```
<div id="myID">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myID').mouseenter(function(){

    $('#myID li').shuffle();

});
</script>
```

Same goes for cwolves script, you want mouseenter